# Ampersand and hash crash my MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, hash, ampersand

I'm using this code to obtain data from a mysql query.

```
    if ($filter == "All" && $filter != "") {date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$todays123 = date("Y-m-d H:i");
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE events.name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.end > '".$todays123."'";
}else{ $todays123 = date("Y-m-d H:i");
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE  events.name LIKE '%".$search."%'   AND events.price = '".$filter."' AND events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.end > '".$todays123."' OR events.description LIKE '%".$search."%'    AND events.price = '".$filter."' AND events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.end > '".$todays123."' OR events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.address LIKE '%".$search."%'   AND events.price = '".$filter."' AND events.end > '".$todays123."'  ";
}
```

Here's my javascript code

```
function user_display() {

var search = document.getElementById("search").value;

if (search == "" || search == null) {
    search="";
} 

var filter = document.getElementById("filter").value;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("table-content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;            
    }
}
    xmlhttp.open("GET","./xxx.php?action=display&search="+search+"&filter="+filter, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

It matches correctly when the search value does not contain  "&" and a "#." When I enter a ampersand or hash symbol the query crashes and does not display anything.

Any suggestions on why it is doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work if you use another portion of the event name, excluding the hash? Check that it's not one of the other parameters causing it to not show up.

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson I was meaning that say you have an event "#1 event", does searching for "1" or "event" return it when searching for "#1" wouldn't?

Comment: @jprofitt yes, that is correct

Comment: I can't help but recommend prepared statements over variable interpolation/concatenation. Of all else, it's just easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should be using `encodeURIComponent()` in your JavaScript. It's likely that you're not getting results because it's not passing anything in the search variable (or cutting it off short). Consider if the search is "a&foo=c&". The URL you are requesting is now `xxx.php?action=display&search=a&foo=c&filter=...` so you end up with another GET variable named `foo`

```
var search = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("search").value);
```

Do the same for `filter` if it's something the user will supply.

Comment: This is the solution. The reason `#` won't work is that servers do not interpret URL [fragment identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (ie, `xxx.php?search=#1`)

Answer (score 0):

change your code to atleast look like this

```
 $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
 $filter = mysql_real_escape_string($filter);
 // hopefully username in $_SESSION is clean else repeat above for that and rerun your query 
 if ($filter == "All" && $filter != "") {date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
 $todays123 = date("Y-m-d H:i");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE events.name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.end > '".$todays123."'";
 }else{ $todays123 = date("Y-m-d H:i");
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE  events.name LIKE '%".$search."%'   AND events.price =   '".$filter."' AND events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.end >   '".$todays123."' OR events.description LIKE '%".$search."%'    AND events.price =  '".$filter."' AND events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.end >  '".$todays123."' OR events.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND events.address LIKE  '%".$search."%'   AND events.price = '".$filter."' AND events.end > '".$todays123."'  ";
  }
```

The above change will atleast make sure that SQL injections can be avoided.

Comment: Please don't recommend SQL parameter escaping. Parameter binding is far superior

Comment: @phil if you re-read my answer it says "change your code to atleast look like this", so `atleast` is the keyword in my answer. I am not recommending it but trying to atleast clean that code. I always use binding and will also recommend it. But considering the code first posted I will have to say that very less info was provided and this at that time 3 hours ago could have be the best answer